# What is the regex for *abc?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to use Regex to find out if a string matches *abc - in other words, it starts with anything but finishes with "abc"?

What is the regex expression for this?
I tried *abc but "Regex.Matches" returns true for xxabcd, which is not what I want.

Comment: Please post exactly what you are looking for as well as any strings you want to fail.

Comment: Not to discount the value of understanding how to use Regex, but if you literally have a single string object and you want to know if it ends with "abc", you can use the string instance method `.EndsWith("abc")`  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz.aspx

Comment: https://regex101.com/ - This site is very helpful to try out regex and test it. And has reference in right bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.*abc$
```

should do.

Comment: you don't really need the `.*`

Comment: Correct. It depends on whether he wants to do more than just check the string - perhaps do something with the match afterwards.

Comment: keep the `.*`  and it will "consume" all the characters before it (i.e. they'll be part of the "match"); remove it and only `abc` will be "matched"

Comment: @nico: It depends on the mode of search. With regex searching (Python: `re.search("abc$", "bla abc")`), you don't need `.*`, but with "matching" (Python: `re.match("abc$", "bla abc")`) you need it because the regex library tries to match the string from the beginning.

Answer (score 8):

`abc$`

You need the `$` to match the end of the string.

Comment: I think I found the answer: ^.*abc\z"

Comment: The difference between `$` and `\Z` is that `$` will match the end of a line. If you have a carriage return in your string, it'll match right before the carriage return. `\Z` will match the end of the string regardless of if it has carriage returns or not.

Answer (score 4):

So you have a few "fish" here, but **[here's how to fish](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)**.

- An online expression library and .NET-based tester: [RegEx Library](http://regexlib.com/)
- An online Ruby-based tester (faster than the .NET one) [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/)
- A windows app for testing exressions (most fully-featured, but no zero-width look-aheads or behind) [RegEx Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/)

Comment: I've been looking for a basic guide to regular expressions and this looks like a handy reference.  +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
.*abc$
```

The $ matches the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

```
^.*abc$
```

Will capture any line ending in abc.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what exactly you're looking for. If you're trying to match whole lines, like:

> a line with words and spacesabc

you could do:

```
^.*abc$
```

Where `^` matches the beginning of a line and `$` the end.

But if you're matching words in a line, e.g.

> trying to match thisabc and thisabc but not thisabcd

You will have to do something like:

```
\w*abc(?!\w)
```

This means, match any number of continuous characters, followed by abc and then anything *but* a character (e.g. whitespace or the end of the line).

Comment: I think your answer represent what the user wants... using the \w parameter, you will catch any words that ends with abc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a string of 4 characters ending in abc use, `/^.abc$/`